# Создание колонок таблицы через jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

При вводе значения в поле ( цифры от 1 до 100 ) должны создаваться колонки таблицы с полями `<input>`.

Если мы, в первый раз ввели 30, то создастся 30 колонок с `<input>`, в каждой ячейке.
Если, во второй раз мы введем 20, то значения `<input>` в первых 20 колонках сохраняются, а след. 10 колонок убираются и значения их `<input>` обнуляются.

И у каждого `<input>` должны быть уникальные класс, к примеру, у первого - `col1`, у второго - `col2`.

Comment: Что значит колонки таблицы? с Уникальными классами? есть для таблицы только `tr` - строки, и `td` - поля. ОбЪясните подробно

Comment: Что конкретно не получается то? Покажите ваши наработки ....

Comment: MedvedevDev, я делал через свойство display. Т.е. при вводе значения я сравнивал его в if и отображал нужное кол-во колонок.Но данный метод использовать глупо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сам додумался до такого:

```js
var x = 0;
function input() {


 if(x > $("#input").val()){
  for (var j = x; j > $("#input").val(); j--){
   k = j-1;
   $(".el"+k).remove();
   $(".el"+k).remove();
  }
  x = j;
 
 }

 else if (x < $("#input").val()){

  for (var i = x; i < $("#input").val(); i++) {
  
   $('.channel_numbber').append('<td class="el'+i+'"><input class="col1_'+i+'"></td>');
   $('.frequency_minAndMax').append('<td class="el'+i+'"><input class="col2_'+i+'"></td>');
  
  }
  x = i;
 }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  .container{
   width: auto;
   overflow: scroll;
  }
  .slova{
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
  }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="input" onblur="input()">

  <table id="myTable">
   <tr class="channel_numbber">
    <td>
              <label for="" class="slova">X</label>
          </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="frequency_minAndMax">
    <td>
              <label for="" class="slova">Y</label>
          </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть идеи по оптимизации или этот код венец творения?))

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что имеется в виду

> 10 колонок убираются и значения их  обнуляются.

Если колонки удаляются, то инпуты, которые были в колонках, удаляется вместе с ними. Вот примерный код:

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    updateTable(this.value | 0);
});

function updateTable(columnsCount) {
    var $table = $('table');
    var $columns = $table.find('td');

    for (var i = $columns.length; i-- > columnsCount;) {
        $columns[i].remove();
        $columns.length--;
    }

    for (var i = $columns.length; i <= columnsCount; i++) {
        //добавление колонок в $table соответствии с шаблоном
    }
}
```